# `ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss' [Tensorflow]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am rather new to Tensorflow, and has been trying to pick up the basics by reading through the guides and documentation on tensorflow.org

I have learnt the basics of how to use the tf.data and tf.estimator APIs and is trying to get them to work together on a basic image model for MNIST.

I am currently following these guides: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

I've changed the original python script to be using `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` rather than `numpy_input_fn` but I am facing the error at the evaluation step. (though not at the training step)

`ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [1,10].`

My code can be found in a python notebook here (only changed the input_fn): https://github.com/quanta0801/tf_scripts/blob/master/mnist/mnist_estimator_baseline.ipynb

Thanks!

PS: any additional links to excellent guides to using tf.data & tf.estimators will be great too! Official documentation cycles between these, keras and the low level APIs which is not conducive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not squeeze dim\[1\], expected a dimension of 1, got 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634133/can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-2)

Answer (score 0):

I had the dim error too, but got fixed by passing the right loss function in `model.compile`