# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have very simple input: Points, and I am trying to classify whether they are in some region or not. So my training data is of the shape `(1000000, 2)`, which is an array of the form:
`[ [x1,y1], [x2,y2],... ]`
My labels are of a similar form (Shaped `(10000, 2)`):
`[ [1,0], [0,1], [0,1],... ]`
(`[0,1]`means the point is in the region, `[1,0]` means it isn't)

My model is set up this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Reads the points and labels from .csv format files
train_data = np.genfromtxt('data/train_data.csv', delimiter=',')
train_labels = np.genfromtxt('data/train_labels.csv', delimiter=',')

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=1, batch_size=100, verbose=1) # ERROR
```

Notice that the input shape is `(2,)`, meaning (according to the [reference](https://keras.io/layers/core/)) that the model would expect arrays of the form `(*, 2)`.

I am getting the error:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2`

and I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

**Stacktrace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/omer/Desktop/Dots/train.py", line 25, in <module>
    model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=1, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node metrics/acc/Squeeze}}]]
```

Comment: Please create a complete example which contains the code that causes the error ([mcve]). As a first guess, note that a Python list is not an array.

Comment: @IonicSolutions Sorry, I wrote them as lists to show their shapes but I use NumPy Arrays, and just kept calling them arrays. Adding an example now.

Comment: Can you try `input_shape=(1,2)`?

Comment: Please include the exact line of code at which the error occurs, and if available the full stacktrace.

Comment: @MattCremeens Got a different error: expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000000, 2)

Comment: Try reshaping using `train_data.reshape(1000000,1,2)`.

Comment: try adding flatten layer before your first dense layer

Comment: @SoK Tried that before, didn't do anything. Tried again, the same.

Comment: Your error likely has nothing to do with the input, but with your loss function. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083984/valueerror-can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-3-for-sparse) for more information.

Comment: @IonicSolutions you are correct, my loss function expected the labels to be indexes. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your labels are of the wrong shape. See [the documentation](https://keras.io/losses/):

> When using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, your targets should be *integer* targets. If you have categorical targets, you should use `categorical_crossentropy`

So you need to convert your labels to integers:

```
train_labels = np.argmax(train_labels, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Per your description of the problem, it seems to be a binary classification task (i.e. inside-region vs. out-of-region). Therefore, you can do the followings:

1. Use `'sigmoid'` as the activation function of last layer.
2. Use one unit (instead of 2) in the last layer.
3. Use `'binary_crossentropy'` as the loss function.

You also need to map your current labels, i.e. `[1,0]` and `[0,1]`, to 0s and 1s.